# UISplitViewController with UIPopoverController crashes on rotate

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

When using a UISplitViewController in portrait , I have a settings popover that I display.  If I rotate the device to landscape while the popover is displayed, the app crashes.

This is because the IPad can only display one popover at a time, and the UISplitViewController shows a popup on rotate -- and that happens BEFORE either view gets a deviceWillRotate message.

It there another message I can capture so I can dismiss my popup before the UISplitViewController shows it's popup?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this, and was unable.  I had a popover displaying from within the detail view, then attempted to rotate to landscape mode, and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I needed was the UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods.  There is a method that gets called right before the popover is created.  That was the hook I needed.